# Data verification php/mysql/jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, import-from-excel

I am trying to retrieve data from excel file and sending it to a php file to check if it exists in the database otherwise notify the user that the data is wrong.

**HTML**

```
<form name="trialInsert" id="trialInsert" action="trial_insert_excel.php"  method="post">
<?php foreach( $data as $row ) { ?>
<tr class="item-row">
<td><input type="text"  name="acc_code[]" id="acc_code[]" class="code" onchange="validate();" value="<?php echo ($row['acc_code']); ?>"/></td>
<td><input type="text" readonly name="int_code[]" id="int_code[]" value="<?php echo ( $row['int_code']); ?>"/></td>
<td><input type="text" readonly name="debit[]" id="debit[]" value="<?php echo ( $row['debit'] ); ?>"/></td>
<td><input type="text" readonly name="credit[]" id="credit[]" value="<?php echo( $row['credit'] ); ?>"/></td>
<td><input type="text" readonly name="debitOld[]" id="debitOld[]" value="<?php echo( $row['debitOld'] ); ?>"/></td>
<td><input type="text" readonly name="creditOld[]" id="creditOld[]" value="<?php echo($row['creditOld'] ); ?>"/></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var code = $('.code').val()
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        source:'autocomplete.php',
        data: 'acc_code='+ code,
        cache: false,
        success: function(response){
            if(response > 0){
                alert(code);
            } else {
                $('.code').addClass('errorClass');
            }
        }
    });
});

function validate(){
    var code = $('.code').val()
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'autocomplete.php',
        data: 'acc_code='+ code,
        cache: false,
        success: function(response){
            if(response > 0){
                alert(code);
            } else {
                $('.code').addClass('errorClass');
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**PHP**

```
$q=$_GET['q'];
$my_data=mysql_real_escape_string($q);
$mysqli=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','03300130','mydb') or die("Database Error");
$sql="SELECT acc_code,acc_desc,acc_type FROM charts WHERE acc_code LIKE '%$my_data%' ORDER BY acc_code";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql) or die(mysqli_error());
if($result) {
    echo 1;
} else {
    echo 0;
}
```

It looks like the return value is wrong or something,the textbox always goes red as if data entered is wrong even if it's not.

Comment: I've got you covered this time, but in future, check the question preview before you hit submit.

Answer (score 0):

you are mixing `mysqli_*` and `mysql_*` commands.

quote from the documentation of [mysql_real_escape_string()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php):

```
Returns the escaped string, or FALSE on error.
```

Since you don't have a `mysql_connect()` call before it will most probably return false. You can check that with `var_dump($my_data);`.

You can use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` instead, alternatively you should look at prepared statements. Note: `mysqli_real_escape_string()` must also be called AFTER the `mysqli_connect()` call.

Comment: i used the same command with an autocomplete example and it returned the desired values but here i don't know why it's not,

Comment: $q=$_GET['q'];
 $mysqli=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','03300130','mydb') or die("Database Error");
 $my_data=mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$q);
 $sql="SELECT acc_code,acc_desc,acc_type FROM charts WHERE acc_code LIKE '%$my_data%' ORDER BY acc_code";
 $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql) or die(mysqli_error()); made the adjustment as you suggested but still nothing i don't know what's the value it's returning,i tried comparing to false,true,0,1,null but nothing

Comment: Use `var_dump()` for debugging.

Comment: it is returning returning a success value even if it finds nothing in the database

Comment: Of course, you are not actually checking what the result contains. As long as there is no error in the query it will be an equivalent of true.

Comment: I have managed to post the array and get a response but the problem is that its reading the first value and not checking each value compared to the one stored in the database.Do you know how to check the values inside an array if it exists in the database.if one is wrong i want it to tell me which one